# Hapi js and Postman Chrome App - subsequent requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, postman, hapi.js

I have this very minimal hapi server:

```js
const Hapi = require('hapi');
const server = new Hapi.Server();

server.connection({
  port: 8080
});

server.route({
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/hello',
  handler: function(request, reply) {

    console.log('hooray');
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('mellow');
      return reply("Hello");
    }, 7500);//7.5 seconds
  }
});

server.start((err) => {
  console.log(`Server started at ${ server.info.uri }`);
});
```

Now if send 2 request with a 2 seconds delay using Postman Chrome App (from 2 different tabs), I get this output on the console:

```
Server started at http://clivend-N56VV:8080
hooray
mellow
hooray
mellow
```

Why is hapi waiting to reply to first request before processing the other?

Thanks!

Comment: EDIT: using the postman native desktop client (instead of chrome app) seems to have fixed the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not hapi that is waiting for the prevoius request. I bet you are testing it in one browser. Try to make 2 request from 2 different browsers or with curl.

Comment: thanks lukasz, it seems like that was the issue indeed